Has anyone succeeded in getting a third party email client to use a public facing email address/Microsoft alias?
Has anyone succeeded in getting a third party email client to use a public facing email address?
For years I had used standard email such as
bill.gates@web.com we'll call variable X
But my email has gotten out and about in the interwebs and I hate getting notices about failed login attempts by the spam bots trying to break into my account.
So I learned about Alias's for Microsoft's email accounts (hotmail, outlook, live, etc.)
I set up aliases. Now I have secretloginforbillgates@web.com (variable Z) as the alias that lets me sign into the account. I fully intended to use X for all incoming and outgoing email traffic. Yes, I still get emails addressed to X but I just noticed that my outgoing email, even though my client Fair Email is configured to use and prominently displays X, the outgoing email is always from my Z address! That kind of ruins the whole strategy I was going for of having a secret login only known to me.
I am looking at all kinds of settings. At first I thought it would be so simple as going to the Outlook website's settings. When signed into outlook, there is a Settings panel accessible via a gear icon in the top right. One of those menu options is "Forwarding and IMAP" and among those options is a dropdown for selecting your default outgoing address. It was already set to X but I changed it to Z, saved, and then again set X as default and saved.
I tested sending an email from Fair Email and it still is coming from Z
I then explores settings inside the app. If I try using the account wizard for signing into X, it tells me that account is restricted from logging in or some such message, which is true. So in the confirmation page I sign in via Z, and have tried both scenarios where from Fair Email I am starting with either email address and verifying the sign in via Z. The wizard doesn't complain and seems to set up the account just fine and I start getting my most recent inbox items.
But then again once I do a test outgoing message, the address it's coming from is Z.
Fair Email also has an alias settings panel and yes I've tried setting that to be X. I've tried multiple approaches but nothing is working on getting this locked.
So how do I set this up so that any third party email client like Fair Email will be using the preferred public facing email address? When I look at "Identities" under Fair Email, the account in question is configured to go to  and expanding those settings I have "Your email address" populated as X.

This may be one of the Pro features. You can get direct support for Fair Email here: https://contact.faircode.eu/?product=fairemailsupport

It is not listed or advertised as one of their pro features.

Its too verbose and I am not following it.

It seems, although I need to do more testing, that once I go to the Outlook settings on Microsoft's website, I can re-enable logging into the same account with either alias. At this point, I then add the email account to Fair Email using the private email address as my method for the "initial" account (for sake of RECEIVING), then I can set up the public email address as an Identity in Fair Email (for the sake of SENDING). Then after Fair Email is set up, I can disable logging into Outlook via this public facing email to achieve that privacy I want.
This set up has persisted for more than 24 hours.
There is no promise or guarantee this will persist indefinitely.
Previous answers are invalid after September 26 2024. Previous answers around the web and inside of Fair Email itself suggests you can use App Password, etc. to set up the identity manually when it doesn't save/register correctly. But Microsoft has deprecated that methodology leaving only OAuth, which works only so long as you have enabled the preferred email address as a log in method on Microsoft's side.

Pro-tip: When setting up the account via wizard, check the box for "Incoming email only (email cannot be sent!)" so that the wrong (private) address does not appear as an option when selecting an email to send from when composing.

A step by step guide was published today on a newly created fairemail subreddit for whatever googlers come across this topic in the future.

You might consider setting rules by moving messages sent to address X to a specific folder, you can ensure that only messages sent to Z will be received and processed, without affecting your primary email address.
In addition, you could also consider using the official Outlook app, which handles aliases more seamlessly. This might not be ideal if you prefer Fair Email, but it could be a temporary solution until the issue is resolved. More information:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-an-email-alias-in-outlook-com-459b1989-356d-40fa-a689-8f285b13f1f2
Hope it helps.

Regarding the latter suggestion: No, the Outlook app is poor. Fair Email doesn't have ads as a huge plus.
For the former: I don't know how I would use that to control the recipient's addresses? Superuser/Stackexchange deleted all my emails from the original post so the point gets lost. But if I email you, I want you to see my email as "zystpublic" but I want it so that no one can log into my outlook account by knowing my email is "zystpublic". I don't care what email you use to send me messages, so me moving emails around to different folders doesn't matter.

This is just a suggestion, although it has ads, but as far as I know, it is only available on outlook.live.com, maybe you can use the Outlook client to avoid it. To get back to the point, using outlook can better manage and switch Alisa to achieve your requirements. For example, your original account is A@outlook.com, but you can change your profile to set it to B@outlook.com, although you are still sending the email from account A, the email in the other person's mailbox shows that he/she received the email from B, and the address also shows B@outlook.com.
